# After AJAX call I can't see the result in my view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I work with Rails 4 and basically I am searching a value on my html webpage traversing the DOM with jquery. I store the value in a variable named **key** and I want to use this value to then make a request that would look like this :
`Record.find(id: key).name`

I have a **User** and a **Record** model. In the `app/views/users`directory I have the partial `_form.html.erb` in which I am doing some javascript.

```js
var key = $('input#record_id').val();
```

And I want this variable to be available in the method **search** of my user controller, so that I can make a request with the parameter **key**.

So I am doing an AJAX call that looks like this :

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click','tr', function(){
  
    var key = $(this).val();
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "/search",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        key: key 
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('success');
      }
      });

});
```

And in my **config routes file** I wrote this route :

```
post '/search' => 'users#search'
```

In my User controller  I wrote the method like this :

```html
def search
  @record = Record.find(params[:key])
end
```

I then created a `search.js.erb`file that has the same name than the method in my controller. In this file I wrote :

```js
$('div#result').html("<%= @record.name %>");
```

**But when I click on one element of my table nothing appears in my div**

I have made a lot of console.log() to see what was in my variable **key** and it is ok there is the right value in it. Also my Ajax call works as in my console log it returns 'success' and in the tab network I can see the task named search with a status of 'ok'.

I had error 500 but I fixed it adding `render json: 'ok'`in my method **search**

Now I am so close of printing the result of  my request `@record.name`but I can't manage to find the solution.

Can anyone give me the solution ? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: if you add `render json :ok` in your action then your `search.js.erb` file wont be rendered. If an action has a render statement then that executes and it prevents it view to be rendered.

Comment: so I just have to remove `render json :ok` ?

Comment: Yeah that should work. Also, after removing render statement, in your rails log check if the search.js.erb file was rendered at all. If they are all fine then you might want to check if `div#resullt` actually exists.

Comment: Have you checked that runniing $('div#result').html("something"); in your javascript console actually shows something in the div?

Comment: Just removing `render json :ok` works well. Thank you @PamioSolanky

Comment: You're welcome @GDMN, I told you I would help you :)

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow how do I do to indicate the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The controller has a convention of returning html by default. In this case, it looks like you're want to return your .js.erb partial. To do so, you need to configure the controller to return a js response.

```
def search
    @record = Record.find(params[:key])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

The format.js in the respond_to block will point the controller to your .js.erb partial. If that fails, post the results of your server's output log, which I imagine is being written to whatever terminal/console you have the app running in locally.

Comment: while its a good practice, its not really needed. Rails automatically renders files based on the request format. For ex. when html request, rails would render a file with .html extension and in case of js request it would render a file with .js extension and likewise for json requests.

Comment: Your code is great for rendering something inline like this  `format.js {render json: :ok}`